# SafeValue must use [property]=binding:

Tags: angular

I got the following error inside my input:

```
SafeValue must use [property]=binding: http://www.myurl.com (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

I did in my component:

```
this.myInputURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('http://www.myurl.com');
```

And in my template:

```
Share URL: <md-input [value]="myInputURL" type="text"></md-input>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You want to show it in input control only?it says, its unsafe to inject it into DOM

Comment: Hmm.. I don't see any other option allowing to copy the link URL fast and easy

Comment: maybe you are missing the proper declaration `public myInputURL: SafeResourceUrl;`. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 4):

change this

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('http://www.myurl.com');
```

to

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('http://www.myurl.com');
```

#### Difference between the two options

##### bypassSecurityTrustUrl

> Bypass security and trust the given value to be a safe style URL, i.e. a value that can be used in hyperlinks or `<img src>`. [source angular.io](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusturl)

##### bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

> Bypass security and trust the given value to be a safe resource URL, i.e. a location that may be used to load executable code from, like `<script src>`, or `<iframe src>`. [source angular.io](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusturl)

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue. While I did not completely read the docs, it seems that sanitizing within the component doesn't work as expected.

What does work however ist sanitizing in the template. For example:

`<object type="text/html" [data]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(app.url)" ngDraggable></object>`

Where `app.url` is declared in the component:

`public url: SafeResourceUrl = "http://example.com"`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -4):

Samething happened to me too. this is because of cross-origion restrictions. Just use embed version link **https://www.youtube.com/embed/video-ID** instead of regular url **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Video-ID**

Yes you will still get same warning, but you can ignore it now as everything will work as expected.